# MCMCglmm multivariate with multiple residuals

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

I am trying to extend a univariate model to a multivariate one within MCMCglmm. Multiple (some correlated) traits were assessed for a number of individuals whose mothers are known (i.e. we know half sib families). There is replication of the families (not the individuals), however due to processing constraints, some replicates everything was taken, and others only the top individuals (from a visual inspection of growth) were taken (and recorded as a sampling type of either 0 or 1). Sampling type  is used as a "fixed effect" and I would like to fit separate residual distributions for the two ways in which we collected the samples. I am having trouble defining the priors to be the correct dimension. A simplified working version of the univariate analysis is shown below:

```
pruni <- list(R =  list(V = diag(2), nu = 2),
              G = list(G1 = list(V = 1e-16, nu = -2),
                       G2 = list(V = 1e-16, nu = -2)))

bm1 <- MCMCglmm(strain ~ sampling_type,
    random = ~ animal + plot,
    rcov = ~ us(sampling_type):units,
    family = 'gaussian',
    data = wv,
    pedigree = pedi,
    prior = pruni,
    burnin = 1000,
    nitt = 6000,
    thin = 100)
```

My understanding (which is obviously not right) is that this should then work for the (again simplified) multivariate case:

```
prmul <- list(R = list(V = diag(4), nu = 4),
              G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 2),
                       G2 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 2)))

bm1 <- MCMCglmm(cbind(form, strain) ~ trait - 1 + trait:sampling_type,
    random = ~ us(trait):animal + us(trait):plot,
    rcov = ~ us(sampling_type):units,
    family = c('ordinal', 'gaussian'),
    data = wv,
    pedigree = pedi,
    prior = prmul,
    burnin = 100,
    nitt =  1000,
    thin = 100,
    pr=TRUE,
    pl=TRUE)
```

However I get an error saying:

> V is the wrong dimension for some prior$G/prior$R elements

Note the above does work with `rcov = ~ us(trait):units` and `R =  list(V = diag(2), nu = 2)` but then obviously it dealing with the sampling type residuals separately.

Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong, and explain the correct way of doing this?